# Почему в данном коде на работает hover?

Tags: css, sass, less

Есть такая html-разметка:

```
<a href="#" class="butt_lang f_left">en</a>
                <ul class="lang_list">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="top_lang">de</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="top_lang">fr</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="top_lang">ru</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="top_lang">esp</a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
```

И css:

```
.butt_lang {
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("../img/polygon.png") no-repeat scroll 33px 20px;
            display: block;
            height: 50px;
            line-height: 40px;
            text-align: center;
            width: 40px;
            &:hover .lang_list {
                display: block;
                width: 25px;
                float: left;

            }
        }
        .lang_list {
            display: none;
        }
```

Проблема в том, что при hover на butt_lang не отображается lang_list
В чем может быть проблема?
Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> &:hover .lang_list {
> ```

Поточу что это не [css](/questions/tagged/css), а [less](/questions/tagged/less), [sass](/questions/tagged/sass), [stylus](/questions/tagged/stylus) или вообще почти(?) любой препроцессор.

Css-правила пишутся без вложенности друг в друга и без амперсандов.

---

А проблема в том, что `.lang_list` не внутри. Вот правильный вариант:

```css
.butt_lang {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("../img/polygon.png") no-repeat scroll 33px 20px;
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 40px;
}

.butt_lang:hover + .lang_list, .lang_list:hover {
  display: block;
  width: 25px;
  float: left;
}

.lang_list {
  display: none;
  margin: 0; /* Иначе мышь перевести на список не выйдет */
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="butt_lang f_left">en</a>
<ul class="lang_list">
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="top_lang">de</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="top_lang">fr</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="top_lang">ru</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="top_lang">esp</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ну ты прям решил вопрос в корне, я то не знал, на чем пишу

Comment: @НикитаЩипилов, есть текст вопроса, где сказано css. Есть единственная метка вопроса - css. Есть код, который только в одном месте отличается от css. Ну ведь логично же?

Comment: Ладно, был не прав, что не поставил тег. Но у лесса 79 подписчиков, а у css 5к

Comment: @НикитаЩипилов, ответ обновлён.

Comment: Спасибо за  ответ

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка была вот тут: `&:hover + .lang_list {` - теги `a` и `ul` соседние.
Если уж задание про препроцессоры, то правильный ответ вот такой, дабы использовать предлагаемую вложенность:

```css
.butt_lang {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("../img/polygon.png") no-repeat scroll 33px 20px;
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 40px;
  &:hover + .lang_list {
    display: block;
    width: 25px;
    float: left;
  }
}
.lang_list {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="butt_lang f_left">en</a>
<ul class="lang_list">
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="top_lang">de</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="top_lang">fr</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="top_lang">ru</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="top_lang">esp</a>
  </li>

</ul>
```